# Is there a light-weight, free XML/XML Schema editor available, with support for XML Schema catalogs and XML Validation?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation, xml-editor, xmlcatalog

I have recently switched from working on *Android* in `Eclipse` to working on `iOS` apps in *Xcode*. I really liked the Eclipse XML editor interface (which has features like auto-complete, CDATA documentation tooltips, linking to schema libraries, and xml validation). Since Xcode is tough on my CPU and Eclipse is also fairly cpu-consuming (and having both open would be hectic), I have opted to not use Eclipse for XML editing, and to find something light-weight that fits the needs listed above.

So, as the title states, **are there any free, light-weight xml and xml-schema editors available?** I looked into CAM editor by Oracle, but could not find a way to add XML Schema catalogs. Apart from that, I have had little luck finding something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up downloading a bare-bones installation of Eclipse, and adding the webtools XML editor plugin. This came out to be about 90MB, and did not cause CPU issues.

Bare-Bones Eclipse download: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.3M2-201209201300/

Webtools plugin site url: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/

Answer (score 1):

Schema catalogs work a little differently in the CAM Editor - you need to generate a dictionary of the components from the schema set you want to use.

First you import the XSD schema into the CAM editor as a new template using the "*" asterix option to pull all components - then generate the dictionary - then add that to the collection you wish to use.

Then you can search components in the dictionary viewer and drag and drop into new XML structures as you design and build those.

There are [Youtube videos here](http://www.niemtrainingvideos.org) that explain this.

Comment: +1 thanks for adding some help for the CAM editor! I'll try this soon.

Answer (score 1):

jEdit programmer's text editor with XML plugin.